# Storing object pointers efficiently for game c++

Tags: class, pointers, vector

I'm making a hooked modding code for GTA San Andreas. The game has its own classes, one of them is `class CPed`. It handles the attributes of random pedestrians created by the game, which is huge in storage. I work with pointers to these objects in my code `CPed*`. Right now I use `vector<CPed*> myList;` to work with these objects/peds.

What is the most efficient way to store these into a container for further use? The game, itself, handles the destruction of these objects.

Comment: Erm. What's wrong with `vector<CPed*>` and why is this tagged boost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::vector` should actually be enough for the most part. In general, when picking a container, you should think about operations you want to do with it, but `vector` is almost always a good start.

If you need key-value lookup, then `std::unordered_map`/`std::map` could be of use as well.

If you need absolutely top performance, you need to benchmark different containers yourself. Using `std::` algorithms and range-for should guarantee easy replacement.